# How to make scrapy continue downloading after losing connection fo a while

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to scrape a website using `scrapy`, but the network in the office is unstable. If we lose network connection for even a few seconds, `scrapy` gets stuck and stops downloading. we can see that the last log is:

```
2018-08-27 11:50:05 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): *.*.org
2018-08-27 11:50:07 [urllib3.connectionpool] DEBUG: https://**.**.org:443 "GET /01313_**0.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 135790
```

I had tried to change the timeout settings, but nothing happened.
thank you!

Comment: Have you tried playing with the options mentioned in https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-fail-on-dataloss ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set `RETRY_TIMES` setting (in `settings.py`):

```
RETRY_TIMES=5
```

Comment: thank you for response, but i did try this and nothing happened. when  we lost connection the script stuck in "Starting new HTTPS connection" .